# Regular expression to match 2 words that are not seperated by a dot (.) so they are part of the same sentence

Tags: regex

I am interested in finding combinations of 2 words that appear in the same sentence.

For example:

Looking for "hello" & "There" that are in the same sentence.

My name is Danny. Hello. I am there. whats up ?  <-- NO MATCH

My name is Danny. Hello there. whats up ?  <-- MATCH

The rule is simple - I dont want a dot character (.) top appear between the 2 words.

Comment: Use `\bHello\b[^.]+\bThere\b`

Comment: Use a case insensitive flag and @anubhava comment should work for you. `(?i)\bHello\b[^.]+\bThere\b`, or modify the expression to match the case of your terms. https://regex101.com/r/3eJ6aO/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try this:

```
\b(H|h)ello\b[^.]+\b(T|t)here\b
```

It matches `Hello There`, `Hello there`, or `hello there`, depending on the case.

Demo is [here](https://regex101.com/r/HdobTZ/1).

Comment: Thank you so much baduker !! this works just perfect. I truly appreciate your effort with the Demo!

Comment: Done. thank you buddy !